# Extracting a <span> tag that contains a text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to extract a span tag like this:

```
<span>Price: $500</span>
```

What's wrong with `doc.xpath('//span[@contains(text(), "Price")]/text()')`?

It's saying it's an invalid expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
//span[starts-with(name(), 'Price')]/text()
```

or

```
//span[starts-with(., 'Price')]/text()
```

or

```
//span[contains(., 'Price')]/text()
```

or

```
//span[contains(name(), 'Price')]/text()
```